# Id value 015d0000009LcU3 is not valid for the Folder_Items__c standard controller

Tags: attachment, inline

this is class

```
global with sharing class treeInlineController { 
  public String actId{get;set;}

    public treeInlineController(ApexPages.StandardController sc){
        List<Attachment> attachedFiles = [select Id from Attachment where parentId =:sc.getId() order by LastModifiedDate DESC limit 1];
        if( attachedFiles != null && attachedFiles.size() > 0 ) {

            actId = attachedFiles[0].id;
            System.debug('@@@@@@ '+actId);
        }
    }
}
```

this is page

```
<apex:page standardController="Folder_Items__c" extensions="treeInlineController" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
  <iframe src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!actId}" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400px"/>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ApexPages.StandardController` should reference to the `Folder_Items__c` object defined as standard controller on the visualforce page. You can not use Folder_Items__c.ID for another object, for example Attachment. You better should change `Folder_Items__c` to `Attachment`.

Comment: kindly send me code which you have suggested to do

Comment: @VipinIndora You should use `standardController="Attachment"`

Comment: still same error show Id value 015d0000009LcU3 is not valid for the Attachment standard controller

Comment: @VipinIndora You should use this page on the Attachment page layout. The rule is: the same standard controller for the same object page layout.

Comment: i use on this attachmenr page layout but error show Content cannot be displayed: Id value a1Cd000000MyDGK is not valid for the Attachment standard controller

Comment: issue resolved, i am doing create wrong list , my data in document list<Folder_File__c> this is the correct and my id api name is documentId__c